How to compare two deep learning image quality assessment models using t-tests and F-tests?
In some papers, I have seen explanations like "the symbol '1', '0', or '-1' represents that the proposed model A statistically (with 95% confidence) performs better, equally, or worse." However, based on my understanding, T-tests and F-tests are used to compare whether there is a significant difference between two groups of data, right?
So I have a question: In the task of image quality assessment, if the predictions of model A are S_A and those of model B are S_B, it seems that regardless of whether there is a significant difference or not, we cannot simply conclude which model is better through T-tests and F-tests. Therefore, according to my speculation, is the comparison of superiority in this case: If the predictions of model A are S_A and those of model B are S_B, and the true label distribution is S_G, we conduct T-tests and F-tests separately for S_A and S_G, as well as for S_B and S_G. Let the results of the two types of tests be denoted as F_{AG}, F_{BG} and T_{AG}, T_{BG}. In the F-test, we compare which one is closer to 1 between F_{AG} and F_{BG}, and the model closer to 1 is considered better. While in the T-test, we compare which one is closer to 0 between T_{AG} and T_{BG}, and the model closer to 0 is considered better. Is it reasonable to understand it in this way?
I attempted to compare the performance of two models, A and B, in image quality assessment. Specifically, I employed T-tests and F-tests to analyze the differences between the predictions of each model (S_A and S_B) and the true label distribution (S_G). I'm seeking clarification on how to properly assess and compare the models' performances.
